# Combining the separate queries from multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql, multiple-tables

Table1

```
ID     | First     |   Last   | Branch
111       Amy           A         10
222       Yuki          B         11
333       Smith         C         10
444       David         D         12
555       Mike          E         13
```

Table2

```
Branch     | Food     |   State
10           Burger        MI
11           Taco          CA
99           Taco          CA
13           Taco          CA
12           Burger        MI
```

Table3

```
Food      | State      | Rating
Burger        MI           bad
Taco          CA           bad
Steak         TX           good
```

QUESTION: How to make the table below:

```
Rating  | CountState   | CountID
Bad          2               5
Good         1               0
```

I am a novice to SQL, so I tried my best to deliver my thoughts into this question. I am thinking of UNION ALL of two queries but failed. Any idea is appreciated. Thank you very much.

```
SELECT a.Rating, COUNT(a.Rating) AS CountState
FROM Table1 a
GROUP BY a.Rating
ORDER BY a.Rating
```

Comment: You have both python and SQL listed, which one are you actually using to do the counts?

Comment: 1) pls describe the logic to calculate countid 2) pls share what you have tried so far

Comment: Table2 is the same Table1.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. I just edited it.

Comment: still there are no good why 1 and why countid

Comment: Your query in your question refers to table1.rating which you show in table3 so this makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your data and what you require for your sample output, it appears you just need a count of Table1 IDs and a distinct count of Table3 States - if that's not correct you need to clarify your relationships and the data better.

The following should give you your desired results

```
select t3.rating,
    count(distinct t3.state) CountState, 
    Count(t1.Id) CountId
from t3 
left join t2 on t2.state=t3.state
left join t1 on t1.branch=t2.branch
group by t3.rating
```

Comment: It works now. Thank you very much. May I ask the theory behind this line? < count(distinct t3.state) CountState,>